# Filezilla on Mac: yubikey authentication?

Tags: macos, ssh, authentication, filezilla, pgp

I am trying to connect to a remote server over ssh using a YubiKey smartcard device. The device contains a GPG authentication key to be used.  This works flawlessly on commandline, but I cannot get FileZilla to use this method.

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set to: `/Users/jc/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh`

That file exists:

```
ls -al /Users/jc/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
srwx------  1 jc  staff  0 Dec 13 00:48 /Users/jc/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

I have tried the interactive option and others in FileZilla, but they prompt me for a password instead of using the key.  I see options to import a private key, but of course that is not possible.

I believe `ssh-agent` is working correctly:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/r6/52hwfppd54gcp282htjvwwcw0000gn/T//ssh-ldRfMkCpTjdT/agent.5716; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=5717; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 5717;
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I found that I needed to launch FileZilla **from the commandline** causing it to inherit the environment settings specifying that it should look for the correct PGP key on the Yubikey device.

I launched FileZilla like so:

```
/Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS/filezilla
```

In the site settings, "Login Type" must be "Normal".